# Creating a method for an operation in a separate class file

Tags: c#, wpf, class, methods

I'm trying to call a method from a different class but with no succes.

I have a `CheckBox` checkBox1 in my program, and I have a button that when I click it I want to uncheck the checkBox1.

If I put I method in the same file like this everything works:

```
public void close()
{
  checkBox1.IsChecked=false;
}
```

But if I create a separate class file (class Close), and put there (in the same namespace, and with "using" the required elements). There no way to make it work. I tried to instance the class as:

```
 Close operation = new Close();
 operation.close();
```

I also tried to put the close method as static, but I was impossible because in my real program I have lots of variables that gives me an error because they are "non static" (?).

I've noticed that a `MessageBox.Show("Hello");` works if I call the method this way, but the checkBox1 still unchanged. What can I do?

Comment: So are you getting a compile error? Does the `Close` class has a `CheckBox` element in it?

Comment: Frankly, I'm failing to understand your question: can you be more complete / specific ?

Answer (score 2):

A basic principle of Object Oriented Programming is [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). It means that a class knows and operates only on the internal member variables of the class.

In your case the class `Close` doesn't know anything of the control variable named `checkBox1` and thus, the method `close` (as written above) cannot operate. It could not even be compiled!. Instead, when the method `close` is part of the Window class it works as expected because the control variable `checkbox1` is a member variable of the window class

However, if I understand your intentions, I advise you to avoid to create separate classes to handle user interface operations. Let the code that works with the UI elements stay with the class where the elements are defined.

Comment: But if I put ":MainWindow" after the class definition (in other file) it can recognize the checkBox, but still can't work properly. Strange. What do you recommend me for getting a clear code? At this moment my code is a mess, and I only have like 10-15 buttons/menus.

Answer (score -1):

The `CheckBox.IsChecked` returns a value of type `bool`, if you are trying to actually change the value of the check box (i.e. checked or not-checked) you need to use a different property.

Try:

```
    public void close()
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
    }
```

This is assuming that the `Close` class indeed has a `CheckBox` control inside of it...  your question is rather vague, and frankly naming a method close is probably not the best practice as `.Close()` is a fairly common method on many classes in WinForms.

Comment: To the downvoter, I have revised this answer... clicked 'Post' before I meant to.  If that helps clarify please remove the vote.  Otherwise would you mind telling me how I can improve my answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote this but I can tell why. Read Steve's answer. `In your case the class Close doesn't know anything of the control variable named checkBox1` explains it.

Comment: Makes sense, except we didn't actually see the code for the entire class `Close`, just a method inside said class.  I will humbly accept the downvote, though it makes me a sad panda ;).  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Also, after reading the question a couple more times I realize I was reading it wrong the entire time...  Didn't see the part about him creating a new class then trying to check the box from there.  Disregard this answer as it is WRONG.  Steve is correct =)